# I wonder how to get the success or failure message upon execution of a ffmpeg command

Tags: php, ffmpeg

I am using a ffmpeg command for watermarking a video.
it does the work but i need to detect wheather it is executed successfully or not.
my command:

```
    $mark = "ffmpeg -i ".$inputvideo." -i logo.png -filter_complex ". '"overlay=x=(main_w-overlay_w):y=(main_h-overlay_h)"'." ".uniqid()."html56.mp4";
```

For output i used something like:

```
$x = exec($mark);
print_r($x);
```

But i am not getting anything printed in place of `$x`.
After some searching I found this statement for `exec` command

```
string exec ( string $command [, array &$output [, int &$return_var ]] )
$s=exec($mark,$var);
```

> $var is my return var.

Now when i print `$var` i am getting an empty array.
Please suggest where i am missing.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> string exec ( string $command [, array &$output [, int &$return_var ]] )

When you do `$s = exec($mark, $var);` your `$var` corresponds to `$output` which is empty because `ffmpeg` outputs information to `sderr` since `stdout` might be used for actual data output.

If you want to get the return code all preceding optional arguments must be specified even if you don't use them:

`$s = exec($mark, $output, $var)`

If you need the actual output you can redirect the `stderr` to `stdout` since you're not using it by placing an `2>&1` at the end of your command or by using PHP's [proc_open()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.proc-open.php) to execute it.